# Spring vault does not use the new token after login

Tags: spring-cloud, hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config, spring-vault

I am trying to read secrets from vault using Spring vault cloud.
I use a service token type.

In my set-up the max_ttl is set to 1h and ttl to 10 minutes, so the token will be renewed at every 10 minutes till the max_ttl is reached. Once the max_ttl is reached, the token will be dropped/revoked and a new login is performed, receving a new token.

The issue is that when trying to read secrets,  the old expired token is still used.

Any idea why this happens?

Using:

- spring-cloud-config-2.2.3
- spring-vault-core-2.2.0
- Kubernetes

Vault audit logs:
[image]

Comment: How does Kubernetes relate to the token issue? Can you post how you bootstrap properties? How do you authenticate against Vault?

Comment: bootstrap.properties:
"vault.uri": "https://vault-url.com"
"vault.auth": "KUBERNETES"
"vault.role": "_soda_role"                
"vault.token":  "******"
"spring.cloud.vault.kv.enabled": "false"
"spring.cloud.vault.uri": "https://vault-url.com"
"spring.cloud.vault.authentication": "KUBERNETES"
"spring.cloud.vault.kubernetes.role": "_soda_role"
"spring.cloud.vault.token": "******"
"spring.cloud.vault.generic.enabled": "false"
"spring.cloud.vault.reactive.enabled": "false".
Nothing strange on Kubernetes side. The issue does not reproduce anymore after disabling reactive support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue does not reproduce anymore as we disable the use of the reactive `org.springframework.vault.authentication.ReactiveLifecycleAwareSessionManager` in favor of the "classic: one: `org.springframework.vault.authentication.LifecycleAwareSessionManager`.

For disabling it, we set:
`spring.cloud.vault.reactive.enabled=false`

Comment: Hum, that sounds like a bug in Spring Vault or Spring Cloud Vault.

Comment: Yes, it seems that somehow the authorization header is not updated after the first lease expired and a new login is performed.